# Filter Values which are greater than its AVG value in Pig/Hive

Tags: filter, apache-pig, average

This is my sample data:

```
+---------------------------+------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+-------+------------------+
|            Car            | MPG  | Cylinders | Displacement | Horsepower | Weight | Acceleration | Model |      Origin      |
+---------------------------+------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+-------+------------------+
| Chevrolet Chevelle Malibu | 18.0 |         8 | 307.0        | 130.0      |   3504 | 12.0         |    70 | US Buick         |
| Skylark 320               | 15.0 |         8 | 350.0        | 165.0      |   3693 | 11.5         |    70 | US Plymouth      |
| Satellite                 | 18.0 |         8 | 318.0        | 150.0      |   3436 | 11.0         |    70 | US AMC Rebel     |
| SST                       | 16.0 |         8 | 304.0        | 150.0      |   3433 | 12.0         |    70 | US Ford          |
| Torino                    | 17.0 |         8 | 302.0        | 140.0      |   3449 | 10.5         |    70 | US Ford Galaxie  |
| 500                       | 15.0 |         8 | 429.0        | 198.0      |   4341 | 10.0         |    70 | US Chevrolet     |
| Impala                    | 14.0 |         8 | 454.0        | 220.0      |   4354 | 9.0          |    70 | US Plymouth Fury |
| iii                       | 14.0 |         8 | 440.0        | 215.0      |   4312 | 8.5          |    70 | US               |
+---------------------------+------+-----------+--------------+------------+--------+--------------+-------+------------------+
```

I want to find out those MPG and HorsePower on basis of each car whose values are greater than their AVG value. Like mpg > AVG(mpg) and HorsePower >AVG(HorsePower).

What I did:

```
r = load '/user/CarData/cars.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (car:chararray,mpg:float,cyl:INT,disp:DOUBLE,hp:DOUBLE,weight:INT,acc:DOUBLE,model:INT,org:chararray);
r1 = group r by car; 
r2 = foreach r1 generate group,AVG(r.mpg) as avg_mpg,AVG(r.hp) as avg_hp,r.mpg,r.hp;
```

It will give me carname,average and bag{mpg}, now I am facing problem to filter from r2. 
I am trying something like:

`FILTER r2 by r.mpg > AVG(mpg) and r.hp > AVG(hp)`

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you reformat your question so the code and sample data is clearly laid out?

Answer (score 0):

In Hive, it would be something like

```
Select Car, MPG, Cylinders, Displacement, Horsepower, Weight, Acceleration, Model, Origin
FROM cars_table 
JOIN (Select AVG(mpg) as a_m, AVG(hp) as a_h) averages ON (1 = 1)
WHERE Horsepower > a_h AND MPG > a_m;
```

Comment: error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 3:44 mismatched input ')' expecting from near 'a_h' in from clause ,this error is coming

Comment: Yes it was untested since I don't have access to your data but do you see the basic idea of how it should be done? Join the averages to the data, and then filter with WHERE to get only the records you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Input :**

```
Chevrolet Chevelle Malibu,18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504,12.0,70,US Buick
Skylark 320,15.0,8,350.0,165.0,3693,11.5,70,US Plymouth
Satellite,18.0,8,318.0,150.0,3436,11.0,70,US AMC Rebel
SST,16.0,8,304.0,150.0,3433,12.0,70,US Ford
Torino,17.0,8,302.0,140.0,3449,10.5,70,US Ford Galaxie
500,15.0,8,429.0,2.0,4341,10.0,70,US Chevrolet
500,45.0,8,429.0,198.0,4341,10.0,70,US Chevrolet
500,10.0,8,429.0,40.0,4341,10.0,70,US Chevrolet
Impala,14.0,8,454.0,220.0,4354,9.0,70,US Plymouth Fury
iii,14.0,8,440.0,215.0,4312,8.5,70,US
```

**Code :**

```
r = load 'test.data' using PigStorage(',') as car:chararray,mpg:float,cyl:INT,disp:DOUBLE,hp:DOUBLE,weight:INT,acc:DOUBLE,mod    el:INT,org:chararray);
r1 = group r by car;
r2  = foreach r1 generate FLATTEN(group) as (car_grp:chararray),(float)AVG(r.mpg) as (avg_mpg:float),
                             (DOUBLE)AVG(r.hp) as (avg_hp:DOUBLE);
j = JOIN r2 BY car_grp, r BY car;
r3 = foreach j generate r2::car_grp  as (car:chararray),r::mpg as (mpg:float),r::cyl as (cyl:INT),r::disp as (disp:DOUBLE),r::hp as (hp:DOUBLE),r::weight as (weight:INT),r::acc as (acc:DOUBLE),r::model as (model:INT),r::org as (org:chararray),r2::avg_mpg as (avg_mpg:float),r2::avg_hp as (avg_hp:DOUBLE);
r4 = FILTER r3 BY mpg > avg_mpg AND hp > avg_hp;
```

**Output :**

```
 (500,45.0,8,429.0,198.0,4341,10.0,70,US Chevrolet,23.333334,80.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the above answers, you don't need to join tables. I feel this will be a optimized version.
**Input data:**

```
Chevrolet Chevelle Malibu,18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504,12.0,70,US Buick
Skylark 320,15.0,8,350.0,165.0,3693,11.5,70,US Plymouth
Satellite,18.0,8,318.0,150.0,3436,11.0,70,US AMC Rebel
SST,16.0,8,304.0,150.0,3433,12.0,70,US Ford
Torino,17.0,8,302.0,140.0,3449,10.5,70,US Ford Galaxie
500,15.0,8,429.0,198.0,4341,10.0,70,US Chevrolet
Impala1,14.0,8,454.0,220.0,4354,9.0,70,US Plymouth Fury
Impala2,25.0,8,454.0,270.0,4354,9.0,70,US Plymouth Fury
Impala3,30.0,8,454.0,290.0,4354,9.0,70,US Plymouth Fury
iii,14.0,8,440.0,215.0,4312,8.5,70,US
```

**Pig Script:**

```
input_data = LOAD '/pigsamples/carinfo' USING PigStorage (',') 
             AS (car:CHARARRAY, mpg:FLOAT, cyl:INT, disp:DOUBLE, hp:DOUBLE, weight:INT, acc:DOUBLE, model:INT, org:CHARARRAY);

group_data = GROUP input_data ALL;
average_values = FOREACH group_data GENERATE AVG(input_data.mpg) AS avg_mpg, AVG(input_data.hp) AS avg_hp;
filter_data = FILTER input_data BY mpg > average_values.avg_mpg AND hp > average_values.hp;
```

**Output:**

```
(Impala2,25.0,8,454.0,270.0,4354,9.0,70,US Plymouth Fury)
(Impala3,30.0,8,454.0,290.0,4354,9.0,70,US Plymouth Fury)
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed `mpg` for `Impala` and `iii` to `19.0` so that query returns something.  You want to avoid self-joins here; his can be efficiently accomplished with [hive windowing functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

**Hive**:

```
select car, mpg, avg_mpg, horsepower, avg_hrspwr
from (
  select car, mpg, horsepower
    , avg( mpg ) over () as avg_mpg
    , avg( horsepower ) over () as avg_hrspwr
  from db.table ) x
where horsepower > avg_hrspwr and mpg > avg_mpg
```

**Output**:

```
Impala    19.0    17.125    220.0    171.0
iii       19.0    17.125    215.0    171.0
```

As far as `Pig` is concerned I think @Sai Kiran Neelakantam's solution is pretty solid.

Answer (score 0):

```
r = load 'A' using PigStorage(',') as (car:chararray,mpg:float,cyl:INT,disp:DOUBLE,hp:DOUBLE,weight:INT,acc:DOUBLE,model:INT,org:chararray);
r1 = group r by car; 
r2 = foreach r1 generate group,FLATTEN(AVG(r.mpg)) as avg_mpg,AVG(r.hp) as avg_hp,FLATTEN(r.mpg) as mpg ,FLATTEN(r.hp) as hp;
r3 = FILTER r2 by mpg > avg_mpg  and hp > avg_hp;
r3 = distinct r3;
dump r3;
```